# How to securely store solutions in a React Native offline game?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm working on a quiz-like game developed for Android with React Native.
I've put all game's data in a JSON file, with all questions and answers, unencrypted.
When the app starts, I load this JSON file and save all needed data in a [Realm Database](https://github.com/realm/realm-js) (mobile database). Then I set the current build number in `AsyncStorage` so this process occurs only when needed (or when app is updated) and not at each app's start. It's working perfectly.

I know that every file, every line of code in a React Native app is considered accessible and not secured. I would like to find a way to keep my game's data secured and private, so it won't be shared online.

Can a user access the json file on his Android phone?
What about root access?

I did think about some solutions :

- if my game was online I could fetch it directly, but my problem is that I need to provide game's data in my app's bundle so my game is offline first
- I could encrypt data stored in Realm database, but the json file I use to fill this database would still be unencrypted so what's the point?
- I could encrypt/decrypt the json file, but how to store the encryption key without being public in the source code?

Unfortunately, I think what I want to achieve is impossible...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Realm` supports encryption on database, find details [here](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#encryption) the encryption section.

> `Realm` supports encrypting the database file on disk with `AES-256+SHA2` by supplying a `64-byte encryption key` when creating a `Realm`.

`AsyncStorage` doesn't support encryptions out of the box. It's not suitable for storing sensitive information. But you can use `SharedPreferance` and `KeyChain` in Android and iOS respectively to store data securely. This library makes it easy for you: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain

Comment: What's the point of encrypting with Realm if the JSON file I use is unencrypted? Does the Realm database is accessible by a normal user? Does the JSON file is accessible too?

Comment: I didn't go thoroughly your use case. If you are using realm you won't need to store any JSON file. Storing JSON file this way is not a good practise and not recommended. If you are using realm, you can store the data in Realm what you are now using storing in JSON.

Comment: I store data in a Realm, but how do I populate this realm? I use my JSON file just to do that. What's the good practice to populate a realm?

Comment: You can keep the JSON file in server and fetch once while populating the Realm.